# Unable to download file from private window wkwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, wkwebview

I am trying to download file from private window using wkwebview unfortunately unable to download the file. this is the response which i am getting.

```
-[DownloadHandler saveDirectoryPathForResponse:][L:124]response <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000434c20> { URL: https://osxDev.slack.com/?redir=%2Ffiles-pri%2FT0B5PPLCX-FF7NT0NNA%2Fdownload%2Fchalte_chalte_-_pagalworld.org } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    );
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        19772
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Wed, 23 Jan 2019 11:08:19 GMT"
    );
    Expires =     (
        "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"
    );
    Pragma =     (
        "no-cache"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apache
    );
    "Set-Cookie" =     (
        "d-s=1548241699; path=/; domain=.slack.com; secure; httponly",
        "x=eo7res6xk440uh3keb6sggrzh.1548239853; expires=Wed, 23-Jan-2019 11:23:19 GMT; Max-Age=900; path=/; domain=.slack.com"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Accept-Encoding"
    );
    Via =     (
        "1.1 5c49044a9bbc82066ce04ae597e1a6a7.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
    );
    "referrer-policy" =     (
        "no-referrer"
    );
    "x-amz-cf-id" =     (
        "jnczFrzoTMCmf-vZHd3M7jgYfKQEl0AEltH7fl74jZE144tGU2MvCw=="
    );
    "x-cache" =     (
        "Miss from cloudfront"
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        SAMEORIGIN
    );
    "x-robots-tag" =     (
        "noindex,nofollow"
    );
    "x-via" =     (
        "haproxy-www-gd85"
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        0
    );
} }
```

But when i am trying with non-private i am able to download and response is

```
-[DownloadHandler saveDirectoryPathForResponse:][L:124]response <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6040006244c0> { URL: https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T0B5PPLCX-FF7NT0NNA/download/chalte_chalte_-_pagalworld.org } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" =     (
        bytes
    );
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "max-age=31536000, public"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Disposition" =     (
        "attachment; filename=\"Chalte Chalte - Pagalworld.org\"; filename*=UTF-8''Chalte%20Chalte%20-%20Pagalworld.org"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        3763833
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "audio/mpeg"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Wed, 23 Jan 2019 11:04:42 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "\"0c3a5aebdf8ab1acab4e098ccb77bc9a\""
    );
    Via =     (
        "1.1 b72519ee5ed84e4e3db077b5b7e93d38.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
    );
    "X-Amz-Cf-Id" =     (
        "aQ6auC2yu5RwLeYuEFyE3TT7tes36MTo5uGnTQ3vxXfGaZ2nAzxNJQ=="
    );
    "X-Backend" =     (
        "imgproxy-prod-pdx-lk25"
    );
    "X-Cache" =     (
        "Miss from cloudfront"
    );
    "X-Content-Type-Options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "X-Robots-Tag" =     (
        noindex
    );
    "X-Slack-Meta" =     (
        S3TA
    );
} }
```

as you can see in private response which is different from non-private response and also content-disposition missing and you can also see response url is different. so in order to download the file even if the WKWebview is in private mode how to do that .

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of file you are trying to download ?

Comment: i've tried audio,video,image nothing is working .

Comment: so why dont you try NSURLSession with download method ? why WKWebView ?

Comment: using NSURLSession to download the files but that chat service called "slack" i am loading this chat service url in WKWebview in private mode and non-private mode and hence trying to download from wkwebview .

Comment: Then for that may be slack have some API to download this kind of data. Try to check slack apis.